# Creating an Observable around an async/await method using RxSwift

Tags: swift, async-await, rx-swift

I am using the AWS Amplify library https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift to communicate with the Cognito service. Most of the functions have been rewritten using the new async/await approach.

Looking at the following method:

```swift
func fetchAuthSession() async throws -> AuthSession {
    return try await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()
}
```

How can I wrap the await call to return an `Observable<AuthSession>` using RxSwift?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `Observable.create` to create an `Observable`.

Use `Task { ... }` to perform `async` work.

Use `Task { ... }` inside `Observable.create` to perform `async` work in an `Observable`.

Something like this should work:

```
let authSessionObservable: Observable<AuthSession> = Observable.create { observer in
    let task = Task {
        do {
            let session = try await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()
            observer.on(.next(session))
            observer.on(.completed)
        } catch {
            observer.on(.error(error))
        }
    }
    return Disposables.create {
        task.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, you need to wrap your async call into a custom `Observable`. However, instead of using the type erased class, I'd recommend creating a `Single`:

```swift
extension Single {
    static func fromAsync<T>(_ fn: @escaping () async throws -> T) -> Single<T> {
        .create { observer in
            let task = Task {
                do { try await observer(.success(fn())) }
                catch { observer(.failure(error))}
            }
            return Disposables.create { task.cancel() }
        }
    }
}
```

A `Single` suits better, since it models an observable that emits exactly one element, which means in the first place better semantics, better transmitting of the intent, and increased compiler support when creating and consuming the observable.

Usage:

```swift
let fetchAuthSession = Single.fromAsync { try await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession() }
```

, or (functional programming style):

```swift
let fetchAuthSession = Single.fromAsync(Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4):

It might help to see a generic version:

```
extension Observable {
    static func create(_ fn: @escaping () async throws -> Element) -> Observable<Element> {
        Observable.create { observer in
            let task = Task {
                do {
                    observer.on(.next(try await fn()))
                    observer.on(.completed)
                } catch {
                    observer.on(.error(error))
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create { task.cancel() }
        }
    }
}
```

Which would be used in this context like this:

```
func fetchAuthSession() -> Observable<AuthSession> {
    .create(Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession)
}
```